# Python: Writing .gz compressed file from a list

Tags: python

i am trying to write the contents of a list into .gz compressed file using gzip module.. for that i am writing the .csv with contents of list, and compressing that into .gz format. So looking for a pretty straight approach without writing the contents into .csv in middle..

`current python code [working]`

```
import re, gzip, csv
from collections import defaultdict

X = [['Apple','x','x','x','x','x'], ['Orange','y','y','y','y','y'], ['Banana','y','y','y','y','y']]

with open('new.csv', "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(X)
        f.close()
Y = open('new.csv', "r").readlines()
b = defaultdict(list)
bkp_filter = ['Apple', 'Orange']
for x in Y:
    for bkp in bkp_filter:
        if re.search(fr'\b{bkp}\b', x):
            b[bkp].append(x)

for k, v in b.items():
    with gzip.open('newzip.gz', 'a') as zip:
        for y in v:
            zip.write(y.encode())
    zip.close()
```

list X has 3 sub list i.e.., `Apple, Orange, Banana`, and there is another filter `(bkp_filter)` list which has `Apple, Orange`. By using re search method, it is writing contents into .gz file with  filtered items found in `bkp_filter`

`output`

```
newzip.gz
Apple,x,x,x,x,x
Orange,y,y,y,y,y
```

`Challenge i am facing:` 
i want to convert this code such a way that, it should write .gz file without writing any .csv file...i.e., by reading list from 'X'

i have tries this..

```
#Y = open('new.csv', "r").readlines()
b = defaultdict(list)
bkp_filter = ['Apple', 'Orange']
for x in X:
    for bkp in bkp_filter:
        if re.search(fr'\b{bkp}\b', x):
            b[bkp].append(x)
```

getting error as `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

after changing `if re.search(fr'\b{bkp}\b', str(x)):` i got new error `

```
    zip.write(y.encode())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

then i tried changing `zip.write(y.encode())` to `just zip.write(y)` .. getting below errror.

```
    zip.write(y)
  File "C:\Users\madmax\anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 260, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

expected output:
same .gz file output but without writing the content into csv file.

please help.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that your x is a list:

```
for x in X:
    for bkp in bkp_filter:
        if re.search(fr'\b{bkp}\b', x):
                                    ^^^ this is ["Bananas", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
```

change it to:

```
        if re.search(fr'\b{bkp}\b', x[0]):
```

Then the same problem is further on. y is a list again, :

```
        zip.write(y.encode())
```

You have more possibilities. If you know all members of y are strings, you can do:

```
y_line = ",".join(y)
zip.write(y_line.encode())
```

Otherwise this might work:

```
for cell in y:
    zip.write(str(cell).encode())
    zip.write("\n".encode())
zip.write("\n".encode())
```

You may open the gzip file in the text mode thus eliminating need for those encodes:

```
for k, v in b.items():
    with gzip.open('newzip.gz', 'at') as zip:
        for y in v:
            zip.write(",".join(y))
            zip.write("\n")
```

2 more notes:

- When you use the with ...open... as something, do not do close. The with constuct will make sure the file is properly closed when leaving context.
- I believe in your example, the cycles for writing the gzip file should be the other way around. You are always opening the same gzip file, and just adding data. Just open it and write everything at once.

Like this:

```
with gzip.open('newzip.gz', 'at') as zip:
    for k, v in b.items():
        for y in v:
            zip.write(",".join(y))
            zip.write("\n")
```

And if the items are not strings:

```
with gzip.open('newzip.gz', 'at') as zip:
    for k, v in b.items():
        for y in v:
            for cell in y:
                zip.write(str(cell))
            zip.write("\n")
```

Comment: Hi Petr, Thanks for your response.. it works perfectly in the example i gave above.. But unfortunately, my list "X" has integers also, hence it was throwing error in my code.. ERROR --> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: this error came when i used X list as X = [['Apple',12334,344,'444','sss','11'], ['Orange',2233,334,'ee','232','333'], ['Banana','y','y','y','y','y']].

Comment: thanks & appreciate your help, help me if there is any possibility to overcome this... i have used "for cell in v" loop as you mentioned above.. but no luck.

Comment: Thanks Petr.. new edit worked perfectly. it had minor issue, that it is zipping all values without comma, and i used this ==> zip.write(str(cell) + ",")

Comment: thanks again, you saved my day. was struggling on this for last 4days.

Comment: With the commas: I wanted to leave some work for you too :-) It's a good training. Please read also my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure if the following works fine, but the idea is that you can use csv writer to write directly into the "gzip" file. Something like this:

```
import re, gzip, csv
from collections import defaultdict

X = [['Apple','x','x','x','x','x'], ['Orange','y','y','y','y','y'], 
     ['Banana','y','y','y','y','y']]

with gzip.open('newzip.gz', 'at') as zip:
    #                         ^
    writer = csv.writer(zip)
    writer.writerows(X)
```